# Вывод данных из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые программисты =))

Передо мной стоит задача вывести данные за несколько дней, за неделю и за месяц в 2е соответствующие колонки.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это сделать.

Как вывести данные за определённую дату я знаю.

```
$datesearch = date("Y-m-d");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date like '%$datesearch%'");
```

Вопрос: как вывести данные за эту неделю и за этот месяц?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

За неделю:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date >= adddate(now(), interval - 7 day)
```

За месяц:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date >= adddate(now(), interval - 30 day)
```

Comment: а как сделать за эту неделю?

Comment: через BETWEEN указать дату понедельника и воскресенья нужной недели

Answer (score 5):

За определенную дату:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE date = <yourDate>
```

За определенный период:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE date BETWEEN <dateBegin> AND <dateEnd>
```

Comment: > По такому запросу нет ответа:

    SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE date = <yourDate>

Comment: вы дату используйте как дату, а не как строку, и производительность увеличится
LIKE не особо то быстр

Comment: > Ну я и пробовал как дату =)) Не омуль же я безмозглый =)))

     $datesearch = date("Y-m-d");
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date = '$datesearch'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: простите в PHP не силен, на это не могу ответить)
Омуль это хорошая рыба, случайно не живешь в Иркутской области или Бурятии?

Comment: Сделаю вид что не понял намёк =))

Comment: Да нее! Я о том что знаешь про рыбу омуль, может ты из Иркутской области или с Бурятии. Можж земляк